# Object to array - quick conversion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a Json structure of this kind:

[image]

this is generate from the backend (I'm using Firebase) and put in a variable :

```
var newJson = {}
```

I'm using AngularJS and ng-repeat though this variable to show the results - and it works. I d like to order the JSON by votes property and I have tried use the angularJS

```
| orderBy: 'vote' "
```

But that doesn't work cos I'm "ng-repeating" though a JSON and not array.
I have tried different solutions showed at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1286
but I couldn't make work any of them.

So I thought to go for the easy road and converting my JSON to array.
I ve tried :

```
 var arreyM = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.newJson.length; i++) {
      arreyM.push(name: $scope.newJson[i].name, pic: $scope.newJson[i].pic, vote:$scope.newJson[i].vote); 
 }
```

but it gave me error - I guess the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
var arreyM = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.newJson.length; i++) {
      arreyM[i]['name']= $scope.newJson[i].name;
      arreyM[i]['pic']= $scope.newJson[i].pic
      arreyM[i]['pic'] =  $scope.newJson[i].vote; 
 }
```

Hope it will help

Comment: It s consol log this : []  ......do I not need to "push" in the arrey the data somehow?

Comment: You have to create the object `arreyM[i] = {};` and also `$scope.newJson.length` will be undefined since newJson is not an array...

Comment: @AlexGarulli try it we are putting data like arreyM[i]['name']

Comment: Yep ...that works ...var arreyM = []

 for (var i in newJson) {
    arreyM [i] = {}

      arreyM[i]['name']= newJson[i].name;
      arreyM[i]['pic']= newJson[i].pic
      arreyM[i]['vote'] =  newJson[i].vote; 
 }