# How would I convert my new Object data I am retrieving from Firebase into the JSON form as I had before

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I just set up my Firebase, angularFire database with my Yeoman, AngularJS app. I use to hard code my data before like so

```
$scope.data = [
    { name: 'NAME', description: 'DESCRIPTION', type: 'TYPE', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC'... },
    { name: 'NAME', description: 'DESCRIPTION', type: 'TYPE', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC'... },
    { name: 'NAME', description: 'DESCRIPTION', type: 'TYPE', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC'... },
    ...
    ...
    More Data...
    ...
    ...
    { name: 'NAME', description: 'DESCRIPTION', type: 'TYPE', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC', etc: 'ETC'... }
]
```

when I uploaded the above data into my Firebase database I had to have a valid form of JSON data so I converted it to this

```
[
    { "name": "NAME", "description": "DESCRIPTION", "type": "TYPE", "ect": "ETC","ect": "ETC","ect": "ETC"... },
    { "name": "NAME", "description": "DESCRIPTION", "type": "TYPE", "ect": "ETC","ect": "ETC","ect": "ETC"... },
    { "name": "NAME", "description": "DESCRIPTION", "type": "TYPE", "ect": "ETC","ect": "ETC","ect": "ETC"... },
    ...
    ...
]
```

which is valid JSON format. Now, when I console.log(firebaseRef), my data is getting retrieved in the form below. This is exactly what I see in my Google Chrome Console.

```
Object {$bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function, $transaction: function…}
    0: Object
         description: "DESCRIPTION""
         name: "NAME"
         type: "TYPE""
         etc: "ETC"
         etc: "ETC"
         etc: "ETC"
         ...more data...
         __proto__: Object
    1: Object
         description: "DESCRIPTION""
         name: "NAME"
         type: "TYPE""
         etc: "ETC"
         etc: "ETC"
         etc: "ETC"
         ...more data...
         __proto__: Object
    2: Object
         description: "DESCRIPTION""
         name: "NAME"
         type: "TYPE""
         etc: "ETC"
         etc: "ETC"
         etc: "ETC"
         ...more data...
         __proto__: Object
    ...
    ...
    ...More Data...
    ...
    ...
```

How would I convert my new Object data I am retrieving from Firebase into the same form as I had before?

Here is a picture of the main difference between the two. The Firebase data I am receiving seems to be an Object with multiple Objects in it and the the data I want/used before is an array of multiple objects.
[image: picture of two different Object data]

Comment: AngularFire 0.8 shouldn't require code like this. It offers a $extendFactory method for transforming data, and $asArray for using data as an array. Generally, you should [not be storing arrays in real-time data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), and this structure looks very strange. You're probably going to a lot of unnecessary work here to solve a specific use case, and complicating this beyond what is necessary. We're probably [solving XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) here.

Comment: The answer to your question is to just call $save(). Since the $ methods are on the prototype, they are not saved back to Firebase. If you are seeing something different, please include version info.

Comment: @Kato thank you for your answer but the reason I am not using version 0.8 of AngularFire is because of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021003/firebase-angularfire-error-module-firebase-is-not-available) as well as this issue I opened from github, (https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire/issues/21) therefore I am currently using version 0.6 of AungularFire

Comment: Also, the data is saving in the Firebase database just fine, it is just when I am reading it from the firebase ref, I am getting the top version of the picture provided above, whereas, I'd like to be able to get or transform that data into array of objects like the bottom portion of the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this url: [Object to array - quick conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012859/object-to-array-quick-conversion)

You need to assign the firebase object to a variable:

```
$scope.firebaseObj
```

and then you can stuff it into your $scope.data object by:

```
$scope.data = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.firebaseObj.length; i++) {
      $scope.data[i]['name']= $scope.firebaseObj[i].name;
      $scope.data[i]['description']= $scope.firebaseObj[i].description;
      $scope.data[i]['type'] =  $scope.firebaseObj[i].type;
      $scope.data[i]['etc1'] =  $scope.firebaseObj[i].etc1;
      $scope.data[i]['etc12'] =  $scope.firebaseObj[i].etc2;
      .
      .
      . 
 }
```

This only will work if every element in the JSON has the same attributes

Comment: Hi ForgetfulFellow. I tried that but it tells me `TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined` and so I tried `console.log(firebaseObj[0]);` and it gave me an `undefined`

Comment: Did you set the `firebaseObj` to your fire base object?

Comment: Yep, `var ref = new Firebase('https://MY_URL.firebaseio.com/');         $scope.firebaseObj = $firebase(ref);` and tried `console.log($scope.firebaseObj[0]);` and it is still `undefined`

Comment: Could you give me the link to your firebase object? I want to work with it in a JSFiddle

Comment: If this helped you, please feel free to mark "answered"